# The "but" in John 1:17

Tags: jesus, law, moses

Why do many people paraphrase John 1:17 like "the law was from Moses **but** grace and truth came by Jesus Christ"? There is no "but" in Greek, at least not in NA28. Is it some kind of bias? For me there is no antithesis between "Moses" and Jesus (Matt. 5: 17-18), however the use of the word "but" suggests there is.

Comment: The KJV has 'but' in italics indicating that it has been added by the translators. Perhaps people are quoting the KJV. As you rightly say, there is no antithesis implied by the text itself.The law is a schoolmaster to bring to Christ, and scripture deals with this as a transition of experience, not an antithesis in logic.

Comment: Verse 13 has the word "but" there to support the contrast and I believe the translators were correct to bring it to verse 17.

Comment: I noticed many modern translations don't have but in 1:17.  I agree with you especially considering 1:14 (ἐσκήνωσεν literally means dwell in a tent [σκηνή]).  Jesus showed the glory of God, just as God showed his glory in the tabernacle.  John is showing a parallel with Moses.

Comment: Also, in verses 10 and 11 the word "kai" (translated "and") can also be translated "but".  Reading those two verses and the contrasts there, a case can be made for "but" instead of "and". eg, 11 He came unto his own, and (but) his own received him not.

Comment: In Greek an adversative conjunction is not always necessary to connect two antithetical statements(e.g. chiasmus).

Comment: The Douay-Rheims Bible reads, "For the law was given by Moses; grace and truth came by Jesus Christ." This seems to be a more literal translation of the verse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This verse is not diminishing the importance of the Law.  On the contrary, it is showing it as a necessary precedent for the coming of Jesus.

The preceding verse 16 is very important too, and helps me explain:

> And of his fulness have all we received, and grace upon grace: 
>   Because the law was given by Moses, grace and truth came by Jesus Christ.

I do not see any dichotomy here, only fulness. The Law flows into Jesus naturally because he came not to abolish the Torah, but to "fill it to the full" (Matt. 5:17).  The same root (pleroo) is used here in Matthew, and in verse 16 of John Ch. 1.  The fulness described is the fulness that includes what happened in the past, which is the giving of the Law (John traces the Word back to the Beginning, actually, so its no surprise the Word is the Law), and the favor (grace) that comes through keeping it.  Because the Law came, Jesus could be born in due time under the Law and fully keep it.  Thereby, even more favor comes upon us, but not so as to wipe out the first dose of favor we were given in terms of keeping the Law. Now favor can be found to be spared the curse of the Law, which Jesus bore, and to be empowered by the Holy Spirit to "keep his commandments" in true love, and not through fear (John 14; 1 John; Jer. 31:31-34). If one believes in Jesus, we establish the curses in the Law as real and applicable things he bore, and therefore we establish the Law itself as a real and applicable thing in its entirety. Remember, Jesus came to bear the curse and to provide atonement.  He did not come to abolish the death penalty for murder, etc. He died the death of a cursed man, and was not stoned like a murderer. Therefore the death penalty was not borne away.

As long as heaven and earth are still here, the Law will still be applicable, for it is the foundation grace is built upon, the foundation Jesus laid in fully keeping it, fully living it.  He was, after all, the Word made flesh. Now the Torah is being written on our hearts by the Holy Spirit. But we wouldn't have gotten this far (as a People) if it wasn't for our Kindergarten teacher, the Law.  Now that we're in college, we don't contradict what we learned in Kindergarten.  2 + 2 is still four and the sabbath is still on Saturday. Nothing is done away with, only enhanced and clarified. Isn't that just like God: he takes something Old, and makes it New again.

Comment: +1. Or as a preacher in my hearing said, "God doesn't make all new things; he makes all things new!"

Comment: @Jacob:I respect your opinion but 2 Corinthians 3 tells us that the OT Covenant was both "done away with" and "abolished". 11 For if that which is done away was glorious, much more that which remains is glorious.13 And not as Moses, which put a veil over his face, that the children of Israel could not stedfastly look to the end of that which is abolished:. Also, Colossians 2:14 tells us that the law was nailed to the cross and "taken out of the way". 14 Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to his cross;

Comment: @Jacob: Also, your stance has a serious contradiction, In your own words you say that grace comes through keeping the law ("and the favor (grace) that comes through keeping it.") The definition of grace is "unmerited" favor, ie mercy without merit or without keeping the law.

Comment: @Alb I respect your opinion as well, but favor in the Hebraic sense is simply favor. (kheyn) = extending favor.  It is something that can be "found":  "But Noah found grace in the eyes of the LORD." - Gen. 6:8.  How is that: "... Noah was a righteous man, blameless in his time; Noah walked with God" (Gen. 6:9).  It doesn't say, "Noah didn't merit the Grace he received."  In fact, the sinners of his generation specifically DID NOT MERIT the favor shown Noah.

Comment: The context of Paul's statement is that the Renewed Covenant administered by Jesus is more glorious than that Ancient Covenant administered by Moses.  Why? Because it builds upon it.  It enhances it, and the Spirit guides our understanding.  But the Foundation is still the Word of God, the Torah.  At a fundamental level, nothing is abolished, but administered through the Spirit by grace.    All Scripture is profitable for instruction in Righteousness.  All Scripture is Spirit breathed.  Having begun in the Spirit, will the law make perfect? no. But it is still profitable to equip therighteous

Comment: @Jacob: Respectfully, there is no idea of "build upon it" in 2 Corinthians 3. It plainly speaks of replacement. The words are the words. V6 the letter (law) kills, the spirit gives life. V7 "ministry of death" (law) which was "to be done away" 9 Ministry of condemnation (law) and "ministry of righteousness" exceeds in glory 11 for that which is done away with (law) had glory, that WHICH REMAINS (the spirit - please note this) V13 law is "abolished" (in Greek=deactivated). V14 "but their minds were blinded (at the reading of the law) but that "veil" is done away with in Christ

Comment: I'm not saying that the law has no purpose; it does. I'm just saying what Paul said and that is the only spiritual purpose of the law is to be a schoolmaster to bring you to Christ. After that it's "Now the Lord is that Spirit and where the Spirit of the Lord is, there is liberty." 2 Corinthians 3:17

Comment: Jer. 31:33 (ISR): “For this is the covenant I shall make with the house of Yisra’ĕl after those days, declares יהוה: I shall put My Torah in their inward parts, and write it on their hearts. And I shall be their Elohim, and they shall be My people." To me, this is not a fundamentally different Torah, it is a fundamentally different way of transmitting it.

Comment: @Jacob; This will be my last comment on this question. Thanks for quoting Jer 31:33; you've made my point for me. Hebrews 10:16 quotes Jer 31:33 and 34 "...and i will remember their sin no more." Why? Because Christ has already fulfilled the requirements of the law and has given them to us for free; that's what receiving Christ's righteousness is all about. Hebrews 10:14 "For by one offering he hath PERFECTED FOREVER those that are sanctified" And Romans 10:4: For Christ is the END OF THE LAW for righteousness to every one that believes. The law of liberty (James 2:12) is NOT the law of Moses.

Comment: "Telos of the Law" = the End-goal of the Law = Messiah . Perfected Forever parallels Torah on their hearts.  What's the problem with that? Can't they receive the righteousness which is of the Law? Rom. 8:4: "That the righteousness of the law might be fulfilled in us, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @alb that the two clauses are intentionally a contrast between the Law through Moses, and grace and truth through Jesus Christ.

Zerwick in his grammatical analysis of the Greek text argues that there is a contrast between the two clauses that is due to Semtic influence and he translates the key points this way (note his inclusion of a contrast):

> > for, *while the Law* … Moses, *grace and truth* … Jesus Christ
> >
> > Max Zerwick and Mary Grosvenor, A Grammatical Analysis of the Greek New Testament (Rome: Biblical Institute Press, 1974), 287.

The Lexham Greek expansion with the Logos software identifies the second clause as a direct contrast between the Law given by Moses and Grace and Truth by Christ.  Chrysostom in his fourth century commentary on John also places a great deal of emphasis on the contrast between the Law and Christ.  Chrysostom's point is to emphasize that while grace and truth were present in the Old Testament but in Christ we have the anti-type and the full expression of these things.  He concludes that John intentionally wants us to see the differences between Moses and Christ.

In this view the "but" of the KJV is only expressing this very old sentiment that there is a great deal of contrast between these two phrases.  Everyone agrees there is some level of contrast, the insertion of "but" is for those who see a greater contrast between the Law of Moses under the Old Testament and Christianity today.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate it "and" if you wish, however there is an indisputable dichotomy and antithesis between the law and grace, by definition. For what is grace but the liberty and relief from the law? As the Pharisee, Paul explained in great detail that the Law of Moses is mutually exclusive with the Grace covenant of Christ in Galatians 2-5 and elsewhere, and even when using words like *having abolished in his flesh the enmity, even the law of commandments contained in ordinances* (Eph 2:15) the apostles do not denigrate the purpose and authenticity of the law, as though it was given by a man and not by God. The law had a purpose and temporal time period until the Messiah comes, as explained in Galatians 3, they are not against or contrary to each other, but the law served a purpose of a guardian until the superior comes, thus they are different covenants and both cannot be valid at the same time.

> **Galatians 5:4** "You are alienated from Christ, you who desire to be justified by the law. You have fallen away from grace."

> **[Heb 8:8-13 ESV]**
> <sup>8</sup>For he finds fault with them when he says: “Behold, the days are coming, declares the Lord, when I will establish a new covenant with the house of Israel and with the house of Judah, <sup>9</sup>not like the covenant that I made with their fathers on the day when I took them by the hand to bring them out of the land of Egypt. For they did not continue in my covenant, and so I showed no concern for them, declares the Lord. <sup>10</sup>​For this is the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel after those days, declares the Lord: I will put my laws into their minds, and write them on their hearts, and I will be their God, and they shall be my people. <sup>11</sup>And they shall not teach, each one his neighbor and each one his brother, saying, ‘Know the Lord,’ for they shall all know me, from the least of them to the greatest. <sup>12</sup>For I will be merciful toward their iniquities, and I will remember their sins no more.” <sup>13</sup>In speaking of a new covenant, he makes the first one obsolete. And what is becoming obsolete and growing old is ready to vanish away.

The sages already explained that when the Messiah comes, the commandments of the Mosaic [law will be nullified](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=messiah%20commandments&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance):

> **The Jewish Spiritual Heroes, Volume II; The Amoraim of Palestine and the Jerusalem Talmud, Introduction 3**
> This aim caused some of the scholars to believe that study of the Torah and the fulfillment of its commandments was most important in life even though one did not agree with the commandments....Others said that after the coming of Messiah all commandments would be done with and there would no longer be any need for written laws.1)נדה ס״א ב׳, מדרש תהלים פּרשה נ״ו.

> **Pri Haaretz, Toldot 5**
> And this is what they of blessed memory meant that in the days of the Messiah the Commandments will be nullified "for the Land will be filled with Understanding of God", and they will possess a different Torah from the Decrees which will become as Commandments. And when a person goes from strength to strength, higher and higher, until he reaches and stands before the root of the whole Torah and Commandments which is "I am HaShem your God...", simple unity and infinite, he then crimps the wings of all the Commandments and Decrees, and they are all nullified. And this is the nullification of the Evil Inclination and elevation of it [back] to prior to the beginning of creation.
>
> **Flames of Faith 13:12**
> According to the Zohar when the Messiah will come there will be a part of pig that will become kosher .

Answer (score -1):

The contrast is between the Law of Moses (Old Covenant) and the Grace of Jesus Christ (New Covenant). So, the contrast is rather substantial. The OT is the testament of the law, which 2 Corinthians 3 tells us is the testament of death. The NT is the testament of grace which 2 Corinthians 3 tells us is the testament of life.

Also, the immediate context of John 1 (King James Version) supports the contrast.

> 10 He was in the world, and the world was made by him, and the world
>   knew him not. 11 He came unto his own, and his own received him not.
>   12 But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the
>   sons of God, even to them that believe on his name: 13 Which were
>   born, not of blood, nor of the will of the flesh, nor of the will of
>   man, but of God. 14 And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us,
>   (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the
>   Father,) full of grace and truth. 15 John bare witness of him, and
>   cried, saying, This was he of whom I spake, He that cometh after me is
>   preferred before me: for he was before me. 16 And of his fulness have
>   all we received, and grace for grace. 17 For the law was given by
>   Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus Christ.

This passage starts with a contrast, stating that “His own” (the Jews) received Him not but others did. Those who did not receive Him, were products of the OT and living by the Law of Moses. However, those who do receive Him (those who trust by faith) have the power to become the sons of God.

Verse 13 continues the contrast stating that these sons of God were not born of blood nor the will of the flesh (metaphors to the self righteous, self willed works of the Law) but these were born of God via the Spirit.

This Word of faith, (Jesus) was made flesh and dwelt among us and we **beheld His glory** which was “full of grace and truth”.  Again, 2 Corinthians 3 tells us that the Old Testament glory (the glory of the Law) was designed by God to fade away like the glory on the face of Moses.  That old glory was replaced by a new more exceeding glory, the glory of the New Testament which is full of grace and truth.

Verse 17 just echoes the contrast of the prior verses stating that the Law was given by Moses (per 2 Corinthians 3 – designed to fade away) but the grace and truth came by Jesus Christ.